# How to investigate invalid certificate

Tags: wcf, x509, certificate-authority

I've got a WCF service with an endpoint configured to use certificate authentication. The client certificate is signed by a root certificate that is installed as a trusted root on the server. But when the client attempts to invoke operations on the endpoint, this fails with MessageSecurityException. The service uses exception shielding so I get limited information, but the eventlog contains the following error:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   ServiceModel Audit 3.0.0.0
Event Category: (2)
Event ID:   4
Date:       3/14/2012
Time:       8:53:05 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   someUrl.net
Description:
Message authentication failed.
 Service: https://someUrl.net/Service.svc
 Action: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT
 ClientIdentity: 
 ActivityId: 
 SecurityTokenException: Certificate failed valiation
```

But if I export the certificate I use on the client computer and import it on the server, it shows up as "This certificate is OK"!

Any idea what I could test or try next?

Answer (score 0):

[Depending on how the service is written you might have some luck with enabling tracing on the server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

With a little bit of luck, your new trace file will contain an explanation about why it rejected the certificate.